# Como instalo pyHook en python

Tags: python

quisiera saber como instalar pyHook en python, yo estoy en windows 11, mi version de python es 3.10.4 y mi version de pip es 22.0.4, cuando lo intento instalar usando el siguiente comando:

> pip install pyHook

me sale:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhook
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyhook

Comment: Ese proyecto está un poco... [desactualizado](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/). ¿Ya lo has probado en Python 3.x antes? Por qué no pruebas [pyHook3](https://pypi.org/project/PyHook3/)?? (que, de paso, también está archivado ese repo...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actualmente pyHook no esta soportado en python 3.10.x

por lo que debes bajar a la ultima version soportada que seria la 3.7.x

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/

pero tambien marcara error a la hora de instalar pyHook
por lo que debes bajarlo directamente del repositorio

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook)

ahora si puedes darle

```
pip install nombreDelArchivoDescargado.whl
```

una alternativa para python 3.10.x seria installar keyboard

```
pip install keyboard
```

documentacion:

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: he instalado la versión 3.7.x de Python, y al intentar instalarme el Pyhook correspondiente me sale que no existe ese archivo y que no es una "supported wheel" en esta plataforma, ¿Cómo lo arreglo?